# web gRPC with TLS on localhost

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-web, grpc-go

I have a Go server and client using a local trusted certificate and they communicate flawless with each other. Now I want the Go server to communicate with a web-grpc instance too. Insecure didn't work as browsers force HTTP2 to go over TLS or deny it fully. And after all; it should work on TLS in production too anyway. Another issue is CORS too, which I can't figure out yet to give to https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web 's version of the server implementation to add origin headers. But first things first.

I serve a simple HTML and Webpack build JS that I serve with a simple Golang FileServer over TLS.

I first generated a new TLS cert/key (that the already-working Go Server/Client pair use successfully):

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=US/ST=State/L=Town/O=Office/CN=www.wp-ts.loc" -keyout ./www.wp-ts.loc.key -out ./www.wp-ts.loc
```

Then I added it to the macOS keychain to be trusted:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain www.wp-ts.loc
```

This is the Protobuf file I use:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package pb;

service GCDService {
    rpc Compute (GCDRequest) returns (GCDResponse) {}
}

message GCDRequest {
    uint64 a = 1;
    uint64 b = 2;
}

message GCDResponse {
    uint64 result = 1;
}
```

Then build with:

```
protoc -I=. gcd.proto \
  --js_out=import_style=commonjs:. \
  --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.
```

This is the simple HTML page I serve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>gRPC</title>
<script src=".//dist/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the JS module:

```
import { grpc } from "grpc";
import { GCDRequest, GCDResponse } from "./gcd_pb.js";
import { GCDServiceClient } from "./gcd_grpc_web_pb.js";

var root_certs = ["www.wp-ts.loc", "www.wp-ts.loc.key"];
var sslCredentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl(...root_certs);
var client = new GCDServiceClient("https://www.wp-ts.loc:3000", sslCredentials);

var request = new GCDRequest();
request.setA(294);
request.setB(462);

client.compute(request, {}, (err, response) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(response);
//   console.log(response.getResult());
});
```

Which is build with Webpack like so (which outputs to `./dist/main.js` and thus read by the `index.html`):

```
npx webpack client.js
```

The `www.wp-ts.loc` test domain is in my `/etc/host` so it can mimic as a domain with the certificate and reroute all traffic to localhost.

Now here's the issue I can't really seem to find in all the big library overhead as this mainly seems to be meant for NodeJS. The Webpack builder with `new GCDServiceClient()` without credentials builds fine, but of course the browser won't allow the non-TLS style (leaving CORS out of the equation for now). Then using the credentials as a test (which of course is dangerous, but I'm trying out along the way and can't find good docs for it on grpc-web style) gives the obvious NodeJS issue that it can't use the filesystem:

```
... // Many lines here, but this is clear enough I guess
ERROR in ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/#USERNAME/Downloads/wp-ts/node_modules/grpc/src'
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js 34:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js
```

Maybe I'm just approaching this totally wrong and I'm also aware that the `grpc-web` implementation is still in a very brittle phase, but how do you make it work to connect correctly over HTTP2/TLS (with certificate) and maybe if known to get the CORS headers to be added to https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web 's server that I add to my Listener in Go at port 3000.

Sorry for big gist, but I hope someone can help me with this. I'm really excited to get going with Go + Browser gRPC/Protobuf :D

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Everything I see for the function 'grpc.credentials.createSsl' is on the NodeJS client side of gRPC and not gRPC-web. I could be wrong though. I have the same setup. I installed nginx on my mac and setup ssl on there with my localhost and grpc_pass to my backend.

Answer (score 0):

you need a `grpcwebproxy` for forwarding your browser request to real grpc server.
https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/go/grpcwebproxy